# I have added two folders to xcode project and now when I try to commit them I get following error

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, commit

> '/Users/me/demo/app/app/MyFolderName'  is not known to exist in the
>   repository and is not part of the commit, yet its child 
>   '/Users/me/demo/app/app/MyFolderName/RequestOperation.h'  is part of
>   the commit

I have tried:

```
svn add MyFolderName
```

But I get:

> svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are
>   already versioned svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested
>   operation

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your folder with full path

```
svn add /Users/me/demo/app/app/MyFolderName
```